# Laravel 5 User activation

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have a strange problem that I can't solve.

When a user is registered, I redirect them to a feed url, open a modal and tell my user to activate his account by clicking the email link that I sent them. But after I click the link, I keep being redirected to the exact same page (feed) and my account isn't being activated. What could be the problem here?

routes.php

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth'], function ()
{
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function ()
    {
        Route::get('activate/{token}', 'PasswordController@activate');
    });
});
```

PasswordController

```
public function activate($token) {
    //get token value.
    // find the user that belongs to that token.
    $activation = User::where("confirmation_code", $token)->get()->first();
    $activation->confirmed = 1;
    $activation->save();
}
```

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php If I remove feed url, it works. But I don't want to do that.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check()) {

        return redirect('/feed');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: could you post all of your routes?  For example I don't even see the '/feed' in your routes file currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your using laravel default authentication system. Do the following.

In your AuthController add the method. This will create the user but not log them in since they haven't activated their account. Please note laravel will automatically login the user hence the function below overrides default behaviour.

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }
    $this->create($request->all());
    return redirect('/feed');
}
```

In RedirectIfAuthenticated.php remove `'/feed'` and instead have a url which users are to be redirected if logged in. Since having feed there will redirect user to the page asking them to activate there account every time they log in.

In the activate function of your password controller there is no logic as to what should be done once user is activated. Add the following lines after $activation->save()

```
Auth::login($activation);
return redirect('/');
```